# 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io

Tags: python, django, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I can't call create filter on my contract, this is my code below. I am able to get the contract and run functions on it, but I cant listen to events:

```
myContract = w3.eth.contract(address="some_address",abi=contract_abi)
```

This is where I run into issues:

```
myfilter_new= myContract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock=0, toBlock='latest')
```

this is the issue I get:

> HTTPError at /testing/
> 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/my_api_key

Comment: Infura doesn't support event filters via HTTP(s). You'll need to use websockets (or connect to a node other than Infura).

Answer (score 1):

As @smarx said, INFURA does not supports filters over HTTP. They do have some support over sockets, but I believe [it is not yet production ready](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/97). It's worth a try, though.

Web3.py has a built-in way to [connect using websockets](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#websocketprovider) that you can initialize like so:

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws"))
```

Comment: Hey, so when i switch over to Web3.WebsocketProvider, I get the following issue:

Comment: InvalidURI at /marblesapp/testing/
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='rinkeby.infura.io', path='/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', params='', query='', fragment='') isn't a valid URI

Comment: You are using the wrong url to connect: `scheme='https'` should be `wss`, and you don't need an API key